# Diferença entre datetime x timestamp?

Tags: java, mysql, banco-de-dados, tipagem

Estou construindo um diagrama no MySQL Workbench e me surgiu essa dúvida, qual a diferença entre os dois?

O java tem problema com alguma delas quando for mandar para a base?

Comment: [Tem mais essa diferença](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101680/91)

Comment: Relacionado: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/411035/112052

Answer (score 31, accepted):

A maior diferença entre `datetime` e `timestamp` é a seguinte:

- `datetime`: representa uma data como no calendário e a hora como encontrado no relógio.
- `timestamp`: representa um ponto específico na linha do tempo e leva em consideração o fuso horário em questão (`UTC`). Por exemplo: quando foi `26/02/2015 16:40`? depende, para mim é nesse momento, para o Japão foi a várias horas atrás, então basicamente o `timestamp` leva em consideração essas questões de fuso horário.

Outro ponto é que geralmente quando se precisa rastrear alterações feitas em registros da base de dados, opta-se pelo uso do `timestamp` pois permite o detalhamento perante a linha do tempo real.

Answer (score 20):

Vou tentar uma resposta alternativa.

DATE: contém apenas uma data civil, sem qualquer consideração de fuso horário, etc. Por exemplo, data de nascimento, ou a data de vencimento de uma conta, ou um prazo legal, é DATE.

DATETIME: contém data e hora civis, novamente sem considerar fuso horário. Se por exemplo o prazo de pagamento é "dia tal até 13:00", é responsabilidade do pagador saber se estamos no horário de verão ou não.

TIMESTAMP: é um número que determina um momento específico. Tipicamente é expresso como o "número de segundos desde 1/1/1970 00:00 em Londres", mas poderia ser qualquer outra base. A ideia do timestamp é que ele vale no mundo todo, ou seja, ele identifica o momento exato em que algo aconteceu. Um acontecimento com timestamp "0" aconteceu em 31/12/1969 às 21:00 no Brasil.

O timestamp é útil para registrar log, e para determinar se A aconteceu antes ou depois de B, mesmo que A e B tenham acontecido em lados opostos do planeta. Por outro lado, o timestamp é inadequado para registrar datas e horas "civis" porque a hora e até a data muda conforme o fuso horário em que o timestamp é interpretado.

Nem sempre a melhor opção é óbvia. Por exemplo, registrar a data de nascimento com DATETIME ou TIMESTAMP? De um ponto de vista matemático, o TIMESTAMP seria ideal porque um bebê nasce num momento bem determinado. Por outro lado, a data e hora de nascimento têm efeitos civis - colocar a data de nascimento diferente da Carteira de Identidade pode causar um monte de aborrecimentos - então é melhor usar DATETIME e o local de nascimento, já que o fuso horário é de conhecimento público.

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi responder porque tem algumas confusões nas outras respostas e não responderem tudo o que foi perguntado.

Vamos começar colocando a [documentação do MySQL sobre o assunto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Os dois tipos, e o `DATE` que não foi incluído na pergunta, são usados para representar um ponto na linha do tempo, ou seja, ele não é uma quantidade de tempo, é para marcar um horário que algo aconteceu.

Obviamente que o `DATE` só tem a data e o `DATETIME` tem também o horário.

Não faz sentido de fato usar `DATE` aqui porque ele não tem horário, algo que os tipos da pergunta têm e é o que faz eles serem parecidos.

É possível, em alguns cenários, usar `TIMESTAMP` para dizer que horário ocorreu algo, mas somente algo que ocorreu depois do primeiro dia de 1970 (pelo menos no MySQL), já que o tempo 0 deste tipo é justamente este, e não o momento do ano seguinte que considera o nascimento de Cristo como é o calendário gregoriano normal que usamos. O `TIMESTAMP` não se preocupa com os aspectos de calendário da mesma forma, ainda que consigamos identificar assim de acordo com o calendário gregoriano quando algo ocorreu.

O mais comum é não fazer isso e usar valor deste tipo como um número sequencial com precisão de até 1 microssegundo, assim como o `DATETIME` também (geralmente o `DATETIME` não precisa muito disto). Então cada unidade de `TIMESTAMP` é 1 microssegundo que se passou. Daí causa a impressão que ele é uma quantidade de tempo, mas não é, só podemos falar em quantidade porque esse ponto no tempo é o deslocamento do início da contagem de cada tipo até o momento que está representando. Isso vale para qualquer ponto na linha do tempo em qualquer tipo que o represente, cada um com suas regras, mas a lógica básica é matemática, não é diferente porque é um tempo.

`TIMESTAMP` não tem fuso horário porque não é para representar algo ocorrido no mundo real, em geral é usado para marcar eventos ocorridos em um computador, daí microssegundos pode ser importante, ainda que o evento talvez nem consiga diferenciar tanta precisão.

O uso inicial deste tipo foi para identificar o momento da criação ou atualização de um arquivo em sistema UNIX, por isso começa em 1970, antes o UNIX não existia. Hoje é muito usado para controlar quando uma linha nova no banco de dados é inserida ou modificada, quando essa informação é importante, além outras formas de formação de *log*. Serve para coordenar processos distribuídos e casos que exijam o conhecimento de quando um evento aconteceu, sempre dentro de computadores.

O uso do `TIMESTAMP` para eventos do mundo real é possível, mas é conceitualmente errado, mesmo que o ocorrido só exista depois de 1970. Imagine usar para registrar nascimento de alguém de antes de 1970, seria completamente falho. E não tem desvantagem em usar o `DATETIME`.

É comum o TIMESTAMP ter capacidade baixa e pode ser um problema, pode inclusive não poder marcar bem eventos futuros, porque ele tem um número máximo. Algumas implementações esse máximo acaba em 2038, daqui a pouco. O MySQL tem esse problema (pelo menos até a versão 8, não sei se é fácil consertar isso sem criar incompatibilidades), por isso ele pode ser uma escolha ruim. Na prática o `DATETIME` acaba sendo necessário se sua aplicação deve durar muito tempo.

## Qual usar?

Hoje, na prática, o `DATETIME` deveria ser usado em todas as situações já que o `TIMESTAMP` tem limitação e poderá estourar em 2038. Se essa limitação for resolvida em versão futura poderá optar por ele em questões internas do sistema, em algo que seja para armazenar um ponto na linha do tempo em evento ocorrido dentro dos computadores e interessa ao sistema.

## Fusos

Há uma confusão sobre fusos nestes tipos. O `TIMESTAMP` não guarda o fuso, o que o MySQL decidiu fazer é que um ponto na linha do tempo que seja usada para inserir o dado considera o fuso usuário que está junto ao dado ou o padrão adotado e ele converte para fuso UTC para armazenar desta forma, ou seja, todo armazenamento é UTC, por isso não precisa armazenar qual é o fuso, é um fuso neutro. O mesmo ocorre de conversão quando o dado é pedido para o banco de dados, há uma conversão para o fuso corrente, que pode nem ser o mesmo que foi usado no momento do armazenamento.

O `DATETIME` também não guarda o fuso desejado. É um problema do programador cuidar disto se for necessário e ele não faz conversão alguma. Mas o MySQL facilita você dizer isso na hora de guardar e pegar a informação.

Por isso servidores deveriam ser usados em UTC sempre. E quase sempre quaisquer dados de ponto no tempo deveria ser em UTC (excetos onde o fuso é parte fundamental do dado no problema que está resolvendo).

Fuso horário é um detalhe humano que pode ou não ser útil e só a apresentação, de acordo com o contexto, deveria considerar. A linha do tempo do planeta não tem fuso horário.

## Conclusão

O Java não tem problemas para trabalhar com esses tipos, se você entender essas limitações, comportamentos, e souber fazer a devida conversão do tipo do Java, se for necessário.