# Tem como saber a hora que um registro foi adicionado ao banco?

Tags: java, sql, banco-de-dados

Gostaria de saber a hora que um registro foi adicionado ao banco. Vou usar esta informação para mostrar a hora que um contato foi adicionado a minha agenda.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Criar uma coluna do tipo **TIMESTAMP**.

No **MySQL**, para guarda data e hora automaticamente ao adicionar algum item basta criar a tabela da seguinte maneira.

```
CREATE TABLE t1 (
  data_criado TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

FONTE: [Documentação MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

Comment: Essa coluna já guarda automaticamente a hora em que foi adicionado? Ou tenho que implementar isso no meu código e inserir no banco?

Comment: qual banco de dados vc esta usando?

Comment: MySQL, no xampp.

Comment: [Cuidado com o bug do ano 2038](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). *The `TIMESTAMP` data type is used for values that contain both date and time parts. `TIMESTAMP` has a range of ' `1970-01-01 00:00:01`' UTC to ' `2038-01-19 03:14:07`' UTC.* CC @BrunoBrito

Comment: Há outra maneira de fazer isso? @VictorStafusa

Answer (score 4):

Na [resposta do Skywalker](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101673/132), foi indicado o caminho de se colocar uma coluna no banco de dados com o tipo `TIMESTAMP` e com `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`.

Entretanto, o tipo `TIMESTAMP` sofre com o [bug do ano 2038](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/datetime.html). Desta forma, o substituto para ele seria o tipo `DATETIME`. [Isso funciona a partir da versão 5.6 do MySQL.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23153922/540552)

Para versões anteriores, o `DATETIME` não pode ser usado com `DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`. Neste caso, há duas possíveis soluções:

1. Abandonar o valor `DEFAULT` e informá-lo explicitamente sempre que um `INSERT` for realizado.
2. Usar uma `TRIGGER`, tal como sugerido [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23153922/540552).