# Erro com valor padrão para campo datetime no MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tive um problema ao tentar executar meu script do banco de dados no servidor. O erro já dá na primeira tabela que o script gera:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
`cd_categoria` int(255) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(100) NOT NULL,
  `cd_status` int(1) NOT NULL,
  `dh_timestamp` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `dh_alteracao` datetime NOT NULL
) ;
```

O erro que acontece é o seguinte:

```
Error Code: 1067. Invalid default value for 'dh_timestamp'
```

Não entendi o que aconteceu, pois preciso que o meu script armazene na coluna **dh_timestamp** a data atual em que se houver um registro de uma coisa qualquer. Como posso solucionar isso?

Comment: Qual é a versão do mysql?

Comment: Sérgio, esse script foi gerado na minha máquina, com o mysql na versão 5.6.21, e agora tenho que subir para um servidor windows com o mysql na versão 5.1.73. Infelizmente, tenho que fazer nessa versão que é inferior a anterior :(

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Não é possível definir uma valor padrão como `now()` ou `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` (que são sinônimos) para colunas do tipo datetime em versões anteriores a 5.6 do MySQL, nesse caso a solução mais simples é trocar o tipo de `datetime` para `timestamp`. Caso a troca do tipo não seja viavel outra solução como dita pelo [sergio nos comentários](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/136738/erro-com-valor-padr%C3%A3o-no-mysql#comment283323_136738) é criar uma trigger para definir o valor padrão, [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23153922/1342547) do SOen mostra como fazer.

**Leitura recomendada:**

[Documentação: timestamp initialization](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html)

[Diferença entre datetime x timestamp?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/52249/91)

[Tem como saber a hora que um registro foi adicionado ao banco?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/101680/91)

[PHP & mySQL: Year 2038 Bug: What is it? How to solve it?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2012589/1342547)

Comment: como voce fez para pegar um comentario com link?

Comment: @pmargreff vc precisa clicar no comentário só que na parte do tempo, ai sim vem o `#342489324` que é o id comentário.

Comment: Não encontrei essa pergunta aqui no SOpt rray; Deixar um +1 aqui... talvez a forma como procurei. Fiz a pesquisa assim : http://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Invalid+default+value+for%22