# Erro ao criar tabela: Invalid default value for

Tags: mysql, centos

Fui criar uma tabela no banco e apareceu seguinte erro:

> Invalid default value for "updated_at"

Aqui está a table a criar:

```
CREATE TABLE  `user` (

 `id` INT( 11 ) NOT NULL ,
 `uuid` CHAR( 12 ) NOT NULL ,
 `fullname` VARCHAR( 512 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `username` VARCHAR( 128 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `email` VARCHAR( 512 ) DEFAULT NULL ,
 `device` TEXT,
 `created_at` TIMESTAMP NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ,
 `updated_at` DATETIME DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
) ENGINE = MYISAM DEFAULT CHARSET = latin1;
```

O banco de dados está criado em uma máquina com **Amazon Linux AMI**, e estou usando versão do cliente **MySQL: 5.5.54**. Será que é algo relacionado com a versão? Como posso resolver o problema?

Comment: [Erro com valor padrão para campo datetime no MySQL](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/136738/91)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

De acordo com o manual:

> As of MySQL 5.6.5, TIMESTAMP and DATETIME columns can be automatically initializated and updated to the current date and time (that is, the current timestamp). Before 5.6.5, this is true only for TIMESTAMP, and for at most one TIMESTAMP column per table.

Que é mais ou menos:

> Desde o MySQL 5.6.5, colunas TIMESTAMP e DATETIME podem ser automaticamente inicializadas e atualizadas com data e hora corrente. Antes da 5.6.5 isto era válido somente para TIMESTAMP, e no máximo em uma coluna por tabela.

Ou seja, só da 5.6.5 em diante.

Até então:

- não podia ser usado em DATETIME
- quando usado em TIMESTAMP só poderia ter uma ocorrência por tabela

> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html

### Possíveis soluções:

- A mais óbvia, mas nem sempre possível, é atualizar o servidor;
- Alternativamente, poderia considerar a possibilidade de tratar numa linguagem cliente, acrescentando o `NOW()` ou CURRENT_TIMESTAMP na query original.

  ```
  UPDATE tabela SET username = "Joao", updated_at = NOW()
  ```

  Mesmo se for usar uma linguagem cliente, recomendo o uso do `NOW()` em vez da função de data da linguagem cliente, pois se em algum momento tiver algum problema com *timezone* ou diferença entre servidores, ao menos o `created_at` e `updated_at` estarão usando a mesma referência de tempo. Isto vale para outras partes da aplicação: sempre que possível, opte por usar uma referência só de tempo para tudo.
- Uma terceira possibilidade seria criar um TRIGGER que fizesse isso por você:

  ```
  DELIMITER ;;
  CREATE TRIGGER `user_bu` BEFORE UPDATE ON `user` FOR EACH ROW
  BEGIN
     SET NEW.updated_at = NOW();
  END;;
  DELIMITER ;
  ```

Answer (score 2):

## Versão do MySQL

Somente a partir da [5.6](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/timestamp-initialization.html) você pode usar `DATETIME` usando o `DEFAULT` que atualiza automático.

Na [5.5](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/timestamp-initialization.html) o tipo de dados precisa ser `TIMESTAMP`

**Editado:**

Havia sugerido na resposta para trocar o tipo da coluna de `DATETIME` para `TIMESTAMP`, porém conforme comentário abaixo, não é possível porque a tabela já possuí uma coluna `TIMESTAMP`.

Comment: Não pode fazer mais de 1 timestamp automático. Nessas versões se fizer o que propôs vai dar o erro `Incorrect table definition; there can be only one TIMESTAMP column with CURRENT_TIMESTAMP in DEFAULT or ON UPDATE clause` - antes da 5.6.5 além de não poder usar em DATETIME, está limitado a uma coluna automatica só.

Comment: @Bacco Tem razão. Não tinha percebido isso. Vou editar a resposta.