# Como trabalhar com timezones sem usar um timestamp?

Tags: mysql, data, datetime, timestamp, timezone

Estava lendo [essa resposta](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2012620/7445826), do Stack Overflow em Inglês, e me deparei com o seguinte trecho:

> For MySQL (or MariaDB), if you don't need the time information consider using the `DATE` column type. If you need higher accuracy, use `DATETIME` rather than `TIMESTAMP`. **Beware that `DATETIME` columns do not store information about the timezone**, so your application will have to know which timezone was used.

De acordo com o trecho em negrito da citação acima, se eu usar o tipo `DATETIME`, a minha aplicação não estará mais *ciente* do *timezone* do usuário, o que ocorreria se eu estivesse utilizando um `TIMESTAMP`, certo?

As perguntas são:

- Como posso salvar a data de um evento que ocorrerá no futuro, salvando também o *timezone* do usuário?
- Como faço para que, mesmo com *timezones* diferentes, o ponto no tempo for o mesmo?

É importante salientar que eu até usaria o tipo `TIMESTAMP` se ele não fosse suscetível ao [*bug* do ano 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/378936/112052).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Na verdade, nenhum dos tipos do MySQL (`DATETIME` e `TIMESTAMP`) guardam informações relativas ao fuso horário. Ambos possuem informações sobre a data e a hora, mas segundo a [documentação](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html), há algumas diferenças:

- `DATETIME`: suporta datas entre `1000-01-01 00:00:00` e `9999-12-31 23:59:59`
- `TIMESTAMP`: suporta datas entre `1970-01-01 00:00:01` e `2038-01-19 03:14:07`

Outro detalhe é que o `TIMESTAMP` sempre trabalha internamente com [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). Ao gravar uma data, ele converte a data/hora do timezone atual para UTC, e ao consultar os dados, converte de volta (de UTC para o timezone atual). Nesse caso, o "timezone atual" é o que está configurado no servidor, mas este pode ser sobrescrito, caso você especifique um timezone na conexão ([por exemplo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36793896): `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=UTC` ou `jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname?serverTimezone=America/Sao_Paulo`, etc).

Isso pode causar confusão caso os dados tenham sido gravados usando um timezone, mas ao consultar usa-se outro (tem exemplos disso [nesse artigo](https://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/22599/mysql-datetime-vs-timestamp-data-type/), e também [tenho um exemplo em Java no GitHub](https://github.com/hkotsubo/java-datetime-book/blob/master/src/main/java/mysql/MysqlTests.java) mostrando esse comportamento). Isso não é um problema se as configurações de timezone são "estáveis", mas não dá para garantir que ninguém nunca vai mudá-las (seja de propósito ou sem querer). Já um `DATETIME` não sofre esses problemas de conversão entre timezones e UTC.

Outro ponto a se notar é que, apesar do nome, o `TIMESTAMP` do MySQL **não** é o mesmo que um [timestamp](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/70473/112052) (um valor numérico - geralmente em segundos ou milissegundos - que indica a quantidade de tempo decorrida desde o [*Unix Epoch*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time)). Obviamente que, como o valor deste está em UTC, ele pode ser convertido para o valor numérico do timestamp, mas graças a esses detalhes de conversão de/para UTC, nem sempre é "óbvio" qual valor que será gravado.

---

Se você quer gravar um instante exato em que algo ocorreu (um ponto na linha do tempo, independente do timezone), e contornar a [limitação do ano 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/378936/112052), uma opção é usar um campo numérico (como um `BIGINT`) e guardar o valor do timestamp (a quantidade de segundos decorrida desde `1970-01-01T00:00Z`), que você pode obter usando sua linguagem preferida (todas possuem alguma maneira de obter isso). Se precisar mostrar essa informação para o usuário, a maioria das linguagens possui mecanismos para converter esse valor para uma data e hora em um timezone específico. E como [`BIGINT` suporta valores bem grandes](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/integer-types.html), você pode até guardar a quantidade de milissegundos se quiser (o maior valor para `BIGINT` *signed* é **2<sup>63</sup> - 1**, e se esse valor representar um timestamp em milissegundos, equivale a uma data no ano 292.278.994 - já se esse valor for em segundos, [equivale a uma data no ano 292.277.026.596](https://ximalas.info/2015/03/10/when-does-the-64-bit-unix-time_t-really-end/)).

Ou seja, nesse caso o banco só guardaria um valor numérico, e a responsabilidade de traduzir esse valor para uma data e hora fica na linguagem que está consultando e manipulando esses dados. A desvantagem é que, por não ser mais um campo de data, não será possível usar as funções específicas do MySQL (como somar dias a uma data, etc), e toda essa manipulação fica fora do banco (embora ainda seja possível comparar se um timestamp é maior ou menor que outro, para saber se um instante está no passado ou futuro, ou ainda colocar os dados em ordem cronológica, já que se trata de um campo numérico). Tem mais detalhes sobre essa abordagem [nesta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24173981).

Se o [problema do ano 2038](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/378936/112052) não for relevante, pode usar `TIMESTAMP` também, se atentando para as configurações de timezone mencionadas acima. Existem ainda funções para converter timestamps de/para datas (como [`UNIX_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp) e [`UTC_TIMESTAMP`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_utc-timestamp)), mas elas também se limitam aos *ranges* do MySQL.

Por fim, [nesta pergunta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409286) tem várias respostas sobre `DATETIME` x `TIMESTAMP`.

---

### UTC e eventos futuros

Em geral a recomendação de "*sempre use UTC*" (ou a variação "*sempre use timestamps*") é válida para a maioria dos casos. Uma "boa prática" muito recomendada é a de converter para UTC o mais cedo possível (assim que recebe o dado, por exemplo) e converter para qualquer outro timezone no último instante (ex: para mostrar a data e hora para o usuário, usando seu fuso horário).

De fato, para muitos casos isso resolve. Mas "sempre" usar uma "boa prática" não vai funcionar 100% das vezes. Um exemplo são datas em eventos futuros.

**Vamos supor que estamos em 2016**, e temos um sistema no qual usuários podem cadastrar eventos futuros. Então um usuário cadastra um evento que ocorrerá em 31 de outubro de 2018, às 10h, no Horário Oficial de Brasília.

Em 2016, a regra do horário de verão brasileiro dizia que ele começaria no terceiro domingo de outubro. Ou seja, em 30 de outubro de 2018, já seria horário de verão, e o [*offset* usado (a diferença com relação a UTC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) é de duas horas atrás do UTC (`-02:00`).

Portanto, a data/hora e *offset* do evento futuro seria `2018-10-31T10:00-02:00`, o que em UTC corresponde a `2018-10-31T12:00Z` ([o "Z" no final significa que a data/hora está em UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Coordinated_Universal_Time_(UTC)), de acordo com o [formato definido pela norma ISO 8601](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/406210/112052)). Então você segue a "boa prática" e grava o valor em UTC no banco. Quando algum usuário quer saber a data e hora do evento, você consulta o valor (que está em UTC: `2018-10-31T12:00Z`) e converte para o timezone do usuário (se for o Horário de Brasília, o resultado será `2018-10-31T10:00-02:00`). Até aqui, tudo certo.

Mas tem um detalhe, que nem sempre levamos em conta: o horário de verão é definido pelo governo, e ele pode mudar de ideia a qualquer momento (basta ver o [histórico](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lista_de_per%C3%ADodos_em_que_vigorou_o_hor%C3%A1rio_de_ver%C3%A3o_no_Brasil)). E nesse caso, mudou mesmo: a regra do Horário Brasileiro de Verão foi mudada por um [decreto publicado em dezembro de 2017](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2015-2018/2017/decreto/D9242.htm). Segundo este decreto, a partir de 2018 o início do horário de verão passaria a ser no primeiro domingo de novembro.

Portanto, pelas novas regras, 31 de outubro de 2018 não está mais em horário de verão, o que significa que neste dia o Horário de Brasília ainda está 3 horas atrás de UTC (ou seja, o *offset* é `-03:00`). E convertendo o valor em UTC que havia sido gravado no banco (`2018-10-31T12:00Z`) para o *offset* `-03:00`, o resultado é `2018-10-31T09:00-03:00` (9 da manhã, uma hora antes do que foi cadastrado pelo usuário). Lembre-se que UTC é um padrão que define um horário a partir do qual os fusos horários se baseiam, e não sofre os efeitos do horário de verão. Ele é um valor absoluto, e se algum timezone muda suas regras (como o *offset* utilizado em cada época do ano), a diferença entre a hora local e UTC também mudará.

Nesse caso, a solução seria guardar um `DATETIME` com a data e hora local (`2018-10-31T10:00`) e gravar o timezone separadamente. Se um usuário só quer saber quando será o evento, mostre a data e hora, e informe em qual timezone aquele dia e horário se referem, caso essa informação seja relevante para os usuários. Se quiser converter para UTC, a maioria das linguagens possui alguma API de data que faz essa conversão, usando as regras do timezone em questão.

Para o timezone, a maioria das linguagens e APIs possuem suporte ao [Time Zone Database da IANA](https://www.iana.org/time-zones), que define identificadores como `America/Sao_Paulo`, `Europe/London` e `Asia/Tokyo`. Cada um desses identificadores possui o histórico de alterações do horário local de determinada região (`America/Sao_Paulo`, por exemplo, [corresponde ao Horário de Brasília](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/259124/112052)).

Cada vez que algum governo resolve mudar as regras do fuso horário de alguma região, a IANA atualiza seu banco e lança uma nova versão. Todas as linguagens e sistemas que usam o TZBD da IANA possuem algum mecanismo para atualizar seus dados, conforme a IANA disponibiliza essas atualizações. No exemplo acima, a mudança da regra do horário de verão brasileiro [foi lançada na versão 2018c (em janeiro de 2018)](https://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz-announce/2018-January/000048.html).

Ou seja, se você tiver gravado a data e hora local separada do timezone, bastaria atualizar o TZBD para que a conversão para UTC passasse a dar o valor correto. Já se tivesse gravado a data e hora em UTC, teria que analisar caso a caso e alterar as datas manualmente (e não é para mudar todas as datas entre outubro e novembro, somente aquelas que foram cadastradas antes de você atualizar o TZDB).

[Neste artigo do Jon Skeet](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2019/03/27/storing-utc-is-not-a-silver-bullet/) tem um exemplo bem mais completo sobre esse problema.

---

Vale lembrar também que, caso você realmente vá guardar os timezones, tenha em mente que eles mudam o tempo todo. No Brasil, por exemplo, tivemos a já citada mudança do início do horário de verão em 2018, e em 2019 mudou de novo (nesse ano [não teremos horário de verão](http://www.planalto.gov.br/ccivil_03/_ato2019-2022/2019/decreto/D9772.htm) - inclusive a IANA [já lançou uma versão contendo esta mudança](http://mm.icann.org/pipermail/tz/2019-July/028249.html)). E nada garante que continuará assim para sempre, pois futuramente o governo pode mudar novamente as regras.

E claro que isso não se restringe ao Brasil. A [União Europeia está a caminho de eliminar o horário de verão](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/eu-scraps-dst.html), e em vários lugares do mundo [sempre tem alguém discutindo](https://www.timeanddate.com/news/time/) se deveria mudar ou não essas regras. Então esse é mais um ponto de atenção, para manter seu sistema sempre atualizado com as novas versões da IANA.

Answer (score 2):

Tem erros aí. Um deles é que todos os tipos que guardam horários no MySQL não guardam fuso horário, especialmente `TIMESTAMP` não faz isto porque sequer faz sentido existir isto neste tipo, tanto que ele converte horários que estejam em um fuso para UTC. E costuma ser o correto na maioria das situações.

Em geral horários deveriam ser gravados normalizados, portanto usando UTC sempre. Em alguns raros casos deveria guardar em um fuso específico e outros raros guardar qual o fuso, e só porque essa informação tem alguma relevância para o sistema (quase sempre não tem, mas os programadores acham que tem).

Se realmente precisa gravar o fuso horário crie uma coluna para armazenar este dado. Bole um formato numérico ou textual que lhe dê esta informação de forma adequada para sua necessidade. Aí o horário seria gravado sem converter para UTC. E trate o horário como um dado composto pelas duas colunas, fazendo conversão se for necessária observando o campo do fuso horário.

Um erro comum que programadores fazem é misturar o dado puro e a representação do dado, o fuso só costuma ser interessante para a representação em cenários específicos, o dado deveria ser armazenado livre disto e normalizado para a forma mais simples que no caso de horário é usando o fuso UTC (convertido para o fuso horário 00:00).

Então por tudo isso `TIMESTAMP` está errado mesmo, ele só deveria ser usado para horários internos do computador que foi a motivação que ele foi criado. Algumas pessoas criam seu próprio tipo de *timestamp* para contornar o problema do ano 2038, que já é outra questão.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta! Confesso que foi bastante esclarecedora. Em relação aos _erros_, desculpe por eles. Você acha que eu edito a pergunta para tentar remover as informações incorretas ou posso deixar como está? ps: Não marquei como aceita para ver se outra pessoa responde também. :)

Comment: Não porque muita gente cometeria o mesmo erro e pode ajudá-las, pra iss o que existem perguntas.