# Retornar data em timezone UTC +0

Tags: php, data, datetime, timezone

Tenho eventos cadastrados com data e timezone, quero retornar a data com timezone 0.

Exemplo do código abaixo:
Tem um evento dia 26/10 às 20h em São Paulo (UTC -3), gostaria que me retornasse 26/10 às 23h, como se eu estivesse em um local de UTC +0.

Pensei em inverter a timezone, ou talvez usar o offset mas não sei se daria certo.
Alguém tem alguma ideia ou caminho para resolver isso?

```
//Data do evento
$evento_data = '2022-10-26 20:00:00';
//Timezone do evento
$evento_tz = 'America/Sao_Paulo';

$tz = new DateTimeZone( ----> $tz_reversa <---- );
$data = new DateTime($evento_data. 'GMT');
$data->setTimezone($tz);
echo $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Não precisa "inverter" nada. Basta criar a data no timezone indicado, usando um [`DateTimeZone`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php), e depois mude para UTC:

```php
//Data do evento
$evento_data = '2022-10-26 20:00:00';
//Timezone do evento
$evento_tz = 'America/Sao_Paulo';

// primeiro cria a data no timezone indicado
// ou seja, 2022-10-26 20:00:00 no timezone America/Sao_Paulo
$data = new DateTime($evento_data, new DateTimeZone($evento_tz));
// depois muda para UTC
$data->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('UTC'));
// pronto :-)
echo $data->format('Y-m-d H:i:s'); // 2022-10-26 23:00:00
```

---

Vale lembrar que guardar a data e hora de eventos futuros em UTC pode causar alguns problemas. Veja mais detalhes na seção "**UTC e eventos futuros**" [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/411097/112052).

Comment: Funcionou perfeitamente! Obrigado!